# What may cause a perfboard to bend?

Tags: pcb

I just finished soldering this little circuit on perfboard and now I realize that the board is bent:

[image: bent perfboard]

I am pretty sure that the board was flat when I purchased it. What may cause this bending?

- Excessive heat?
- There are some long solder bridges in that part of the board; is it possible that the solder shrinks when getting solid/cold?

**Edit:** Those boards are sold as "bakelite" boards at a local shop. I'd say they are low quality boards (eg. the solder pads tend to come off easily.)

Comment: I have no idea what to tag this. Ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I have noticed that perfboard does all sorts of bad things: corrosion, bending, peeling, etc. It even bends when stacked neatly in a pile and is not in use.

So I think the best answer to your question is "it just does", or perhaps "it uses cheaper, less stable laminate methods, and all laminates are at risk of bending." (Plywood for example often warps when one side is exposed to air and the other is not.)

My recollection is that it is made of [FR-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FR-2) (synthetic resin) and not FR-4 (bonded epoxy) like commercial circuit boards, and is not as stable a base.

Answer (score 6):

I think you actually hit the nail on the head at the end of your question:

> it possible that the solder shrinks when getting solid/cold

The coefficient of thermal expansion of solder is around 20 ppm/C, meaning that when you heat it up 200 degrees C to melt it, its length increases by a factor of 200 * 20 * 10^-6 = 0.004. When it cools, it grabs onto the perfboard, and then the length decreases that much.

You could probably calculate the radius of curvature of the board, knowing the length of contraction and assuming it will bend into a circle.

Comment: I (ill-advisedly) filled a perfboard almost completely with solder because I was too stupid to buy stripboard instead, and it bent severely (severely un-flat, but not so severely that it wasn't usable)

Answer (score 3):

It's not very stable stuff, because of all those holes. I think it's caused by having all the components on the same side, and all the connections on the other side. I've had large four-layer PCBs warp during manufacture for similar reasons - unbalanced copper areas on the outer layers. Boards made by another supplier were OK, though.

Answer (score 2):

These boards are fiberglass and epoxy laminate.

When heated above their glass transistion temperature, the epoxy will become less rigid and more 'rubbery' resulting in warpage and permanent deformation.

Perf boards which are usually made with cheaper and thinner materials than most other PCB's will warp with heat greater than 140 deg C.

Comment: That perfboard looks more like phenolic than fiberglass.  I don't think I've ever seen any fiberglass perfboard, with the exception of proto boards that featured drilled plated through holes and were made by a full-fledged double-sided circuit-board making process.  Phenolic is soft enough to allow holes to be punched rather than drilled.  Such holes are too uneven to be plated, so phenolic boards are only used in applications where a single-sided board will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be the way you had the board clamped when you soldered
the components. If the board had a bend when it was clamped it
may not be able to "spring back" after the components are soldered.
Not clamping the board could also cause the problem.

What type of board are you using? If you are using epoxy-paper I
would switch to epoxy-glass. It should spring back a lot
better. It also is less likely to crack and break. 
I like Vector 169P84WE. The parts I use for breadboarding
are listed at the bottom of http://wiblocks.luciani.org/FAQ/faq-tools.html

Comment: Those are likely "epoxy-paper" boards. I did not clamp the board while populating it.

Comment: They kind of look like epoxy-paper. If you can hold the board flat
with a vice or clamp while you solder it may bend less when the clamp
is removed.

Answer (score 1):

> What may cause a perfboard to bend?

Per my experience: mostly low cost materials that are marginally suitable for the application.

In physical terms, the bending would be caused by mechanical hysteresis under thermal stresses, thermally-induced "annealing"/stress relaxation, and strain induced by re-freezing solder on a large proportion of pads.

Another possibility - and I've seen that happen - is a slightly mis-scaled hole pattern. If the holes aren't exactly on a 2.54mm pitch, then longer packages such as DIP-40 will tend to introduce a bending moment.

I'm not sure what companies are still left that make professional quality perfboards - Vector? Schroff? I wouldn't expect a quality one to bend due to normal heat of soldering a prototype. I had some blue Schroff FR-4 plated-through-hole perfboards I got in the 90s, and I abused them quite a bit by modifying the circuitry several times - they remained perfectly straight.

The board pictured is not FR-4 but some phenolic resin and perhaps glass fiber if you're lucky, or bleached cellulose fiber.

If you'd put together the circuit on a FR-4 perfboard that had better than rock-bottom temperature rating - FR-4 comes in several such ratings - I expect it'd perform nothing like what you'd seen.

You may end up with better results by ordering your own custom perfboard on FR-4 from one of the many mass PCB makers (JLCPCB, PCBWAY, etc). They may charge extra for high hole density, but it may still be cheaper than expensive brand names, and should perform just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I built a class AB amplifier, and the board  bent. FR4 was used this time. Board size: 53x80 (original size  was 100x100, it was cut for other projects).

There was:

- bakelite
- FR3/FR4 (laminate, material FR4, epoxy resin reinforced with fiberglass.)

Both bent for me during projects. When I was done with my amplifier, I tried to not abuse the heat, due to bending, and pads falling off. Even with FR4, I have fallen-off pads (not many but it lost some of its looks). It bent about 0.8 mm up in the middle.

I also tried bakelite first because it was little bit cheaper. I regretted buying it.

I had to remove some components and play around with that, because I didn't have the circuit 100% right. I had to figure out things, so I had to do it.

At least the FR3/FR4 pads are sticking to the board better.

At least now I know not to blame myself because the board has bent, also all my remaining stored boards also bent like 0.2-0.8 mm in the middle of the board.

I have a project, it was an autoclicker, I perfectly knew what and where to put and solder, and the board is perfectly straight still (FR4 used).

The conclusion is that whatever you do, do not heat the board for long, and don't use more than 380°C when soldering.

Comment: I think there's something special about protoboards that just makes them very cost sensitive and prone to being made from worst performing materials. I've had fairly large FR-4 protoboards with lots of plated through holes, and they were perfectly straight. They also cost about $15 for a Eurocard-sized board... in 1990s... purchased from Distrelec AG. So you get what you pay for...